# Laravel : Redirect from AuthenticatesUser file throw error route not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

After successfully login, redirect with define user role it is return an error that route not defined.

> InvalidArgumentException
>   Route [list-activity] not defined.

`file path : vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUser.php`

Function:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if($user->user_role=='Admin'){
        return redirect()->route('list-activity') ; // return error
    }elseif($user->role=='User'){
        return redirect()->route('front.welcome') ;
    }
}
```

My web.php file code

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('front.welcome'); });
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::middleware(['web', 'navigation'])->group(function () {
require_once("admin/web.php");  });
```

`Note: Added web.php file on admin folder`

My routes admin\web.php file code

```
 Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
 Route::get('lists-activity','ActivityController@listactivity')->name('lists-activity'); });
```

And here is my controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class ActivityController extends BaseController
{
   public function listactivity() {
   dd("hello");
} }
```

Comment: try this `return redirect('admin/lists-activity');`

Comment: @Sohel0415 now return `Class navigation does not exist
`

Comment: Have you defined middleware called `navigation` in `App\Http\Kernel`? You set it `Route::middleware(['web', 'navigation'])` here

Comment: @Sohel0415 using a fresh copy and just create a login.what should i do ?

Comment: @Javed show us your ``App\Http\Kernel`

Comment: @Sohel0415 thanx gt it what i frgt `'navigation' => \App\Http\Middleware\NavigationMiddleware::class,`

Comment: It would be better if you say thanks to @Ohgodwhy rather than me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're named route does not match with your `route()` method.

```
Route::get('lists-activity','ActivityController@listactivity')->name('lists-activity');
```

In the above code your route is named `lists-activity`

But in your controller, you are using

```
return redirect()->route('list-activity');
```

To fix this, you have to replace the name of the route inside your controller's method:

```
//return redirect()->route('list-activity');
return redirect()->route('lists-activity');
```

Comment: This is the right answer, you need a route named `list-activity` in order to access a route with the name... list-activity